# Rocket REST API return global object

Tags: api, rest, rust, rocket

I'm starting to learn Rust and the rocket framework https://crates.io/crates/rocket.

I have a dumb question that I can't figure out.

How do I return my_universe that I created on the first line of main() when calling GET /universe/ports/21?

```
fn main() {
    let my_universe = universe::model::Universe::new();
    rocket::ignite().mount("/universe", routes![ports]).launch();
}

#[get("/ports/<id>")]
fn ports(id: u16) -> universe::model::Universe {
    // need to return my_universe here
}
```

The issue I'm having is that if I define my_universe within the route controller ports(), it'll recreate the my_universe  object on each request. Instead, I need the route to return the same my_universe object on each request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing non-mutable state in rocket is fairly easy. You can add the state with `manage` during the build of rocket.

```
rocket::build()
  .manage(my_universe) // put the shared state here
  .mount("/universe", routes![ports])
```

If you want to return this state in a route you will have to add both `serde` as a dependency and the `json` feature of *rocket*.

```
[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.2", features = ["json"]}
serde = "1.0.147"
```

You can now annotate your `struct` with `Serialize` so we can send it as a JSON response later.

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Universe {
    /* ... */
}
```

And access this state in your route with a `&State` parameter.

```
#[get("/ports/<id>")]
fn ports(id: u16, universe: &State<Universe>) -> Json<&Universe> {
    Json(universe.inner())
}
```

Here we can access the `inner` value of the state and return it as `Json`.

---

So far, the state is immutable and can not be changed in the route which might not be what you want. Consider wrapping your state into a `Mutex` to allow for interior mutability.